# JSON - enter in a object second level

Tags: javascript, json

Good afternoon!

After this small request

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    var sumInfo = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    var objName = Object.keys(sumInfo);
                    console.log(sumInfo);

                }
```

i get this json object:

```
{"teste":{"id":3132576,"name":"Teste","profileIconId":28,"summonerLevel":1,"revisionDate":1445611659000}}
```

how do i get the ID of this object? Because i can't do something like this:

```
sumInfo.objName.id;
```

Thanks !

Comment: You would use `sumInfo.teste.id`.

Comment: Maybe sumInfo[Object.keys(sumInfo)[0]].id would do

Comment: Thank you! Its a very simple answer haha. Im a very beginner

Answer (score 1):

I take it you won't know the name of the 1st level objects? If that is true, this should work:

```
for (key in sumInfo) { //for every key in the object 'sumInfo'
    console.log(sumInfo[key].id); //log to console the id of each object
}
```

If you do know the name of the 1st level objects, this will suffice:

```
console.log(sumInfo.teste.id);
//or
console.log(sumInfo['teste'].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `objName` is a string variable where `objName = "teste"`, you need to use bracket notation:

`var id = sumInfo[objName].id`

Answer (score 0):

Add a handle and then simply access it?

```
var obj = {
    "teste" : {
        "id" : 3132576,
        "name" : "Teste",
        "profileIconId" : 28,
        "summonerLevel" : 1,
        "revisionDate" : 1445611659000
    }
};
alert(obj.teste.id);
```